# Ingress loadbalanding issue(healthcheck) with GCP Cloud Endpoint (ESPv2)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to use Ingress instead of Service type: Loadbalance in front of my Cloud Endpoint enabled API. And I face the "UNHEALTHY" status for the backend. I added readiness and liveness probes for the ESPv2 but I still see the same issue.

Is there anybody working with Ingress in front of Cloud Endpoint service?

Comment: Did you run nginx with : ```hostNetwork:true``` ?

Comment: The GCP's Cloud Endpoint uses ESPv2, which uses Envoy Proxy. I believe the GCP's builtin Ingress controller is using NGINX. I don't know what "hostNetwork" attribute is and where should I use it though.

Comment: Unhealthy backend error could mean that the `healthchecks` created by an `Ingress` are failing. Have you checked the `Ingress` resource `healthchecks` in `GCP Cloud Console`(Web UI)?  You can check it by following this path `Cloud Console` -> `Network Services` ->  `LoadBalancing` -> `NAME OF YOUR INGRESS` -> `Healthcheck`.

Comment: I checked that place and it shows the same problem with backend. Look, I set the liveness and readiness probs for the ESPv2 and also for my own dummy server within my deployment. They must be passed before the containers show the ready state. And both of them are in ready state and they can accept query by using nodeport. How Ingress doesn't consider ESP one as healthy. I try Ingress with my dummy service and it works fine with it and not with the ESP. 

I am sure the rocket scientists at google have some explanation for it.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue

Comment: Yes, I solved the issue. It happens when the liveness and readiness probes for the Pod is TCP and not HTTP. In this case, GCP is confused and uses HTTP which doesn't exist on the container. You need to go to the failed backend and edit the health check method to the proper one. wait for a couple of seconds and everything will be fine.